# Inserting text when opening a file

Tags: vim, vi

I am trying to edit a new file with vim. The first line should be a given text string.
Something like

```
vim -c ":insert TEXT" filename.txt
```

The behaviour I am looking for is that filename.txt is opened with vim and the word TEXT appears on the first line.

The command above is obviously wrong.. any suggestion on how to obtain this behaviour.

Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Convoluted solution:**

This seems to do exactly what you want. It does not save the file, but inserts the text.

```
vim -c ':exe "normal iTEXT"' filename.txt
```

This works the same, but exits insert mode after the text is entered:

```
vim -c ':exe "normal iTEXT\<Esc>"' filename.txt
```

**Previous, incorrect solution. But helpful:**

Similar to Hal's answer, but you can have vim grab text from standard input:

```
echo "This is some text" | vim - -c ":w filename.txt"
```

And vim will open with "This is some text" on the first line, and the `-c` command will call the `:w filename.txt` command as soon as vim opens.

Comment: The solution provides the same behaviour. The file is immediately saved. The behaviour I was looking for was allow the user to save the file only if required.

Comment: I see. I think I understand your question a little better now. Though you don't mention that you don't want the file immediately saved. Not sure of a solution however.

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
$ vim -c "put='insert text here'" foo.txt
```

If you are bothered by the extra blank line, then make it

```
$ vim -c "put='insert text here'|2d" foo.txt
```

You could also try `call append(0, 'TEXT')` (untested) instead of using `:put`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use echo to output to a file and open it subsequently?

```
echo "TEXT" > filename.txt | vi filename.txt
```

Comment: This solution would create the file prior opening. Which I do not want.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it combine with the echo command:

```
echo ":insert TEXT" | vim -c 'w filename.txt' -
```